# how to inquire an iterator in python without changing its pre-inquire state

Tags: python, oop, iterator

I built an iterable object A that holds a list of other objects B. I want to be able to automatically skip a particular object B on the list if it is flagged bad when the object A is used in a for loop.

```
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.Blist = [B(1), B(2), B(3)] #where B(2).is_bad() is True, while the other .is_bad() are False

  def __iter__(self):
    nextB = iter(self.Blist)
    #if nextB.next().is_bad():
    #   return after skip
    #else:
    #   return nextB
```

However, I cannot figure out how to write the conditional that is commented in pseudo code above, without skipping the iteration inquired (the else clause fails)

Thanks!

Comment: You could encapsulate your iterators in objects having a 'peek ()' function and an overridden next (). It should contain a state variable that keeps track of which one was called most recently, next () or peek (). If next () is called after itself, it should call next () on the encapsulated object, return the result and also store it in a buffer. If it was called after a peek () it should return the buffer. Peek () always call the encapsulated next (), return it and store it in the buffer ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator function:

```
  def __iter__(self):
      for item in self.Blist:
          if not item.is_bad():
              yield item
```

A generator function is marked by the keyword `yield`. A generator function returns a generator object, which is an iterator. It will suspend execution at the `yield` statement and then resume processing when the calling routine calls `next` on the interator.

Comment: Also, does it need the first line? can the loop be simply `for item in self.Blist:`

Comment: You are right, it does not need the first line. I have modified my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def __iter__(self):
    nextB = iter(self.Blist)
    for b_obj in nextB:
        if b_obj.is_bad():
            yield b_obj
```

A simplified example:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, cond):
        self.cond = cond

    def is_bad(self):
        return self.cond

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Blist = [B(True), B(False), B(True)]

  def __iter__(self):
    nextB = iter(self.Blist)
    for b_obj in nextB:
        if b_obj.is_bad():
            yield b_obj

a = A()
for x in a:
    print(x.is_bad())

>> True
   True
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose Hans option as best simlpy because that's the one who skip the bad B, yours is the opposite. But both were what I needed :)